# Basis of $\mathcal{P}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I have to show that $A=\{t^{3},2t^{2}-t+3,t^{3}-3t^{2}+4t-1\}$ is not a basis of $\mathcal{P}_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ - but not using dimension theory or something like that, I mean I have, a priori, to show that these polynomials are linearly independent and that $\mathcal{P}_{3}(\mathbb{R})=[A]$.

Well, I could show that these three polynomials are linearly independent, but I couldn't see why $A$ does not generate $\mathcal{P}_{3}(\mathbb{R})$.

I tried to show that 
$$p(t)=at^{3}+bt^{2}+ct+d\in\mathcal{P}_{3}(\mathbb{R})$$
is unique written using $p_{1}(t)=t^{3}, p_{2}(t)=2t^{2}-t+3, p_{3}(t)=t^{3}-3t^{2}+4t-1$:
$$p(t)=\alpha\cdot p_{1}(t)+\beta\cdot p_{2}(t)+\gamma\cdot p_{3}(t)$$
where I got the following system:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix} \alpha+\gamma=a \\ 2\beta-3\gamma=b \\ -\beta+4\gamma=c \\ 3\beta-\gamma=d \end{matrix}\right.$$
and then
$$\alpha=\frac{11a-3c-d}{11},\quad\beta=\frac{c+4d}{11},\quad\gamma=\frac{3c+d}{11}$$
So, my question is: why can I conclude that $\mathcal{P}_{3}(\mathbb{R})\neq[A]$?

Comment: Does your solution $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ really satisfy $2\beta-3\gamma=b$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Add twice the third equation to the second one to get $5\gamma = b+2c$. Then add three times the third equation to the last to get $11 \gamma = d+3c$. This will give you $11b + 22c = 5d + 15c$. So you must have that $11b +7c - 5d = 0$, which of course isn't satisfied by all elements of $\mathcal{P}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$